# How do I auto skip a another line instead of word wrapping in vs code for java?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, word-wrap

I enabled word wrap settings in vs code for java. I realized it don't actually skip a line:

[image: This is happening.]

But I want to all of them is a different line, and it will be saved that way:

[image: that way.]

Here is my word wrap settings:

[image: Here is my word wrap settings.]

And this is my settigns.json file:

```
{
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
"files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
"workbench.colorTheme": "One Dark Pro",
"python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\atleo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python.exe",
"workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
"window.zoomLevel": 0,
"C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
"editor.suggestSelection": "first",
"vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
"python.languageServer": "Pylance",
"[Log]": {

    "editor.wordWrap": "off"
},
"java.configuration.checkProjectSettingsExclusions": false,
"python.autoComplete.addBrackets": true,
"python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true,
"workbench.editorAssociations": [
    {
        "viewType": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb",
        "filenamePattern": "*.ipynb"
    }
],
"editor.rulers": [
    { "column": 80,
    "color": "#307777"}
],
"kite.showWelcomeNotificationOnStartup": false,
"java.configuration.runtimes": [

],
"[java]": {

    "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false
},
"files.associations": {
    "*.java": "java"
},
"java.refactor.renameFromFileExplorer": "autoApply",
"git.autofetch": true,

"editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
"[markdown]": {

    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "editor.quickSuggestions": true
},
```

}

Comment: type a shorter string, or press Enter after the `=`, or use a formatter, word wrap ONLY changes the VIEW of the file

Comment: I gave these just for example, sometimes it can pass 80 characters with methods. Yes, it is done by pressing _Enter_, but I want it to be automatically corrected as I type. I tried `Language Support for Java (TM) by Red Hat` as a **formatter**, but it didn't work. Is there a formatter you can recommend or do you know how to set its settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature will be added in next update, which can [Provide better format configuration experience](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-pack/issues/604).

**[UPDATE]**

With java extension latest release, you can achieve this feature from Command Palette then choose **java: open java formatter settings with preview**. Detailed information please view [Java on Visual Studio Code Update – May 2021](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/java/java-on-visual-studio-code-update-may-2021/).

Comment: Hi @Tewhem. the feature you want has been released, please see my answer update and have a try :)

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked for me, sorry for the late reply.